# What is the different between creating a list and inserting a value at the same time vs. in 2 steps?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to give value `pre[1]` to a new list by using `List <Integer> list = new  ArrayList(pre[1]);`, but I got an empty list .

When I make this into 2 steps: first create an empty `list1`, then add `pre[1]` to my `list1` , it works: `list1` contains `2`.

Can anyone tell me why?
I was expecting the same result.

I was thinking `List <Integer> list = new  ArrayList(pre[1]);` is creating a list, and initializing  the value to `pre[1]`, but is not working, what is the problem??

```
int[] pre =new int []{1,2,3};
List <Integer> list = new  ArrayList(pre[1]);

List <Integer> list1 = new  ArrayList();
list1.add(pre[1]);
```

Comment: Read the documentation, there is no constructor for that. Instead you are calling a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) that sets the initial size of the list to whatever value is in pre[1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [the documentation of `ArrayList`'s constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#constructor.summary).

TL;DR: There is no constructor that receives the new element(s) that the initialized `ArrayList` should contain.
The constructor that you're calling is [the one that receives an integer as argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-), which has its capacity defined according to the argument (i.e. `pre[1]` or `2` in your case).

Comment: As an aside that may have lead to the confusion on OP's side: an array is not a `Collection`

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `ArrayList` receives `initialCapacity` not the element.
So in your case you are creating List with `initialCapacity` 2 i.e pre[1].

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

You may want to try `List.of` in java9

```
List.of(pre[1], pre[2]);
```